# CORS error occurs when HTTPS applied to the my server using Let's Encrypt

Tags: angularjs, node.js, https, cors

I have a Digital Ocean Linux server.
I deployed my REST API and also front end in the same server.
My Back End runs using Node.JS and front end using AngularJS.

After enabling HTTPS, I changed all the REST URLs into HTTPS.
Like this :

```
var mainHost = "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:7000/api";
```

Now I'm getting this CORS error :

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:7000/api/user_manage/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

I am using Node.JS CORS plugin also.

```
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

This started when I added HTTPS and I tried many things. Including changing the .htaccess and adding some meta tags. Still no good. What is the reason for this ? Why CORS error comes after adding HTTPS ? Please help me to solve this.

This is the controller call for the service layer :

```
sessionService.getAllSessions(100, 0).then(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      $scope.allSessions = data.data;
});
```

And this is the service layer :

```
getAllSessions: function (limit, offset) {
    return $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: host.session_manage + '/session/' + limit + '/' + offset
    }).then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    });
}
```

I'm not using headers in the service call as you can see in the above section.

This is the server code snippet :

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var morgan = require("morgan");
var config = require("./config");
// var cors = require('cors');

var app = express();

// app.use(cors());

// app.use(cors({
//     origin: 'https://xxxxxx.com'
// }));

app.use(function (req, res, next) { res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"); next(); });

app.set('views', './app/views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));

var session = require('./app/routes/session')(app, express);
app.use('/api/session_manage', session);
app.listen(config.port, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("localhost:7000");
    }
});
```

Thank you guys.

Comment: This seems to be the same environment described in your question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53756621/after-adding-https-my-servers-are-not-working-and-getting-cors-error — and if so, then the reason for the failure is unrelated to your CORS config. Instead it sounds like it’s some problem with SSL not actually being properly configured on the `https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:7000` server.

Answer (score 1):

You are in production you don't want to allow CORS access for all origins but if you need to allow cross origin requests from some specified host(s) you can do add the following code:

`server.use(cors({
  origin: 'https://example.com'
}));`

This will allow https://example.com to send cross origin requests to your Express server without the Same Origin Policy getting in the way.

You can also enable CORS for a single Express route

`server.get('/endpoint', cors(), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This has CORS-enabled for only this route: /endpoint'})
})`

If you want to allow multiple origins you need to use a function (for origin instead of a string) that dynamically set the CORS header depending on the origin making the request and a white list that you specify which contains the origin to allow.

`var whitelist = ['http://example.com', 'http://othersite.com'];
var options = { origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  }
}
server.use(cors(options))`

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer buddy . I'm checking this solution and will get back to you soon... :-) Hope you can save my day :-)

Comment: can you pls send me your http request how you are making it from angularjs. you also need to send headers from http request to handle cors.

Comment: or else you can also do without cors module `app.use(function(req, res, next) {
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
            next();
        });`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/chanakaDe/082fb1ba34eb2d8b26895f3e6f1b1cdd check thus gist buddy

Comment: This "app.use(function(req, ...... " , Do i need to add this in server side or client side bto ?

Comment: you have to add it in server side.

Comment: @ChanakaDeSilva actually i dont have access off gist at my workplace. could you pls share me what errors of cors you are getting exactly. also it would be good you can add your node and angularjs snippet.

Comment: Please check the question again, I added all the code there.